# FluentScheduler or Windows Service for MVC4 tasks? Advice please

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5, scheduled-tasks, fluentscheduler

I have a MVC4 EF5 application that has a new requirement to sync records via a service call at least once a day.  This will require pulling a JSON object from an external database, comparing the values to an existing entity and then logging the differences and updating the entitiy to reflect the data pulled from the services.

This seems like something that would ideally be in a separate Windows service but I'm not sure how I can do this while still access my Entities that are within my MVC project.  Has anyone had to do anything similar and have any advice on the best way to go about this?

Conversely, what about creating a controller for these actions and schedule calling the action? This seems simple, but do I need to worry about timeouts, etc?

Thanks

Comment: Fluentscheduler might be another option as it seems like I can add it to my application_Start.  Has anyone used this? https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you. If you find anyone who has used it previously share the experience.